# Clarification on NFS export options

Tags: nfs

Do the NFSv4 `root_squash` and `all_squash` (and their `no_` alternatives) export options have any effect if the filesystem is exported read only? Basically, all all these lines equivalent:

```
/var/www/html 10.0.2.0/24(ro,insecure,sync,root_squash,all_squash)
/var/www/html 10.0.2.0/24(ro,insecure,sync)
/var/www/html 10.0.2.0/24(ro,insecure,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. `ro` means that the whole file system is entirely read-only, regardless of the file permissions, but if `root_squash` is not set, `root` will be allowed to *read* files he might not be allowed to read if `root_squash` is set.